# Inserting data from form into database PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am trying so send data from a form into my database, but I doesn`t seem to work. The tables fields are correct. sI someone able to see what is going wrong?

Form:

```
<form class="myForm" role="form" action= "idea.php" method ="POST">
    <h1 style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:30px; text-align:center; color:#0f4155;">Idea Form</h1>

    <p1>Name:</p1>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">

    <p1>Originator:</p1>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="originator" placeholder="Originator">

    <p1>Alternative Contact</p1>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="altcontact" placeholder="Alternative Contact">

    <p1>Problem to Solve</p1>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="problem" placeholder="Problem to Solve">

    <p1>Description</p1>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>

    <p1>PO</p1>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="po" placeholder="PO">

    <p1>Archetypical Client</p1>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="archclient" placeholder="Arcetypical Client">

    <p1>Urgency</p1>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="urgency" placeholder="Urgency" style="margin-bottom: 20px">

    <p1>Technology/Platform</p1>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="technology" placeholder="Technology/Platform">

    <p1>Number of Sprints</p1>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="sprints" placeholder="Number of Sprints">

    <p1>Progress</p1>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="progress" placeholder="Progress">

    <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { //if new idea is being added

    $id = '';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $originator = $_POST['originator'];
    $altcontact = $_POST['altcontact'];
    $problem = $_POST['problem']; 
    $description = $_POST['description']; 
    $po = $_POST['po'];
    $archclient = $_POST['archclient']; 
    $urgency = $_POST['urgency']; 
    $technology = $_POST['technology']; 
    $sprints = $_POST['sprints']; 
    $progress = $_POST['progress']; 
    $status = "submitted"; 


    $strsq0 = "INSERT INTO idea (`id`,`name`, `originator`, `alternative_contact`, `problem`, `description`, `po`, `arch_client`, `urgency`, `technology`, `sprints`, `progress`, `status`) VALUES ('" . $name . "," . $name . "," . $originator . "," . $altcontact . "," . $problem . ", " . $description . ", " . $po . "," . $archclient . ", " . $urgency . ", " . $technology . ", " . $sprints . ", " . $progress . ", " . $status . "');"; //query to insert new idea
    if ($mysqli->query($strsq0)) {
        echo "Insert success!";
    } else {
        echo "Cannot insert into the data table; check whether the table is created, or the database is active. "  . mysqli_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: For one, you don't quote your values in the VALUES part of your SQL query, so at the very least that will fail. Read up on prepared statements. (You just has values as one giant single column string).

Comment: Inserting two times `VALUES ('" . $name . "," . $name ` name

Comment: remove `id` from insert into idea ()

Comment: Please add some detail to your application. You are connected to the database before you launch the query sql?

Comment: Please escape your user supplied values.  Or bind your parameters.  Otherwise you are prone to SQL injection.

Comment: I tried your answer farhan but now i am getting aan servercode 500

Comment: @user3356007 try to print your query with php and exit code before query run. and then copy that query and run in phpMyadmin and check if there is any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `id` is `auto increment` then remove it from query of add `NULL` in `values()`, also quotes are not properly managed

```
$strsq0 = "INSERT INTO idea (`name`, `originator`, `alternative_contact`, `problem`, `description`, `po`, `arch_client`, `urgency`, `technology`, `sprints`, `progress`, `status`) VALUES ('$name','$originator','$altcontact ','$problem', '$description', '$po','$archclient', '$urgency', '$technology', '$sprints','$progress', '$status')"; //query to insert new idea
```

To more debug

```
echo "INSERT INTO idea (`name`, `originator`, `alternative_contact`, `problem`, `description`, `po`, `arch_client`, `urgency`, `technology`, `sprints`, `progress`, `status`) VALUES ('$name','$originator','$altcontact ','$problem', '$description', '$po','$archclient', '$urgency', '$technology', '$sprints','$progress', '$status')";
exit;
$strsq0 = "INSERT INTO idea (`name`, `originator`, `alternative_contact`, `problem`, `description`, `po`, `arch_client`, `urgency`, `technology`, `sprints`, `progress`, `status`) VALUES ('$name','$originator','$altcontact ','$problem', '$description', '$po','$archclient', '$urgency', '$technology', '$sprints','$progress', '$status')"; //query to insert new idea
```

Then copy this printed query and run in `phpMyadmin`, check if there is any error after running printed query.

Comment: True, though only one part of the problem :)

Comment: also i think you have include name 2 times in values part check that also

Comment: i am not sure about quotes as not sure what are the data types for fields in DB

Comment: Much better. Now if only op would use prepared statements.

Comment: single quot was started in values clause and end quot was in last . values(' "value1", "value2", "value3" '), it should be like value('value1', 'value2', 'value3') if all values are string

Comment: for example http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_insert_colname and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: I have find out that when I only try to add 1 field to the database it works when i try it with 2 it doesn`t

Comment: I am working in bluemix so everytime i want to check i have to deplay i am testing it now

Comment: i have removed some fields and tried to debug the query this is the result

Comment: INSERT INTO test (name, originator) VALUES ('killer, insteict '); is pushing the right values

Comment: No it's not. You're only sending a single column value. The query should be `INSERT INTO test (name, originator) VALUES ('killer', 'instinct');` Notice the quotes.

Comment: it is strange that my auto increment starts with an id of 2

Comment: @user3356007 you need to truncate your table after that all data will be removed and your auto increment will start from 1, is query running fine now?

Comment: "INSERT INTO test (name, originator) VALUES ('killer, insteict '); is pushing the right values" this is not a right syntax

Comment: I don't believe TRUNCATE will reset auto increment. But it doesn't matter anyway, just leave it.

Comment: yes no need for truncate, ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT=1

Comment: Jon thanks for your help you ('" . $name . "'','" . $name . "',''' . $originator . "')

Comment: is this is not working? ('$name','$name','$originator')

Comment: that also works but like you said only for string I think still finding it strange that id count from 2 to 12 to 22 to 32

Comment: where to put this in my code farhan AUTO_INCREMENT=1

Comment: run this in phpMyadmin ALTER TABLE idea AUTO_INCREMENT=1, this will set auto increment value to 1

Comment: quotes are required when value is string, otherwise don't use quotes

Comment: it is still doing +10 very strange